# onBackPressed() isn't working?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I'm developing an android application in eclipse....
When I click a button in main activity, it's taking me to another activity(Say "cources").... 
But, when I clicking the back button, it's totally closing the app instead of getting back to main Activity.
I tried {onBackPressed()} method but no use.... plz help me...

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
}
```

What to do???

Comment: where are your logcat and show the onActivityResult

Comment: post your manifest file and two activities

Comment: why you call setContentView after super.onBackPressed?

Comment: Post your code where you handle button click in the main activity.

Comment: Did the answer helped?

Answer (score 3):

**1. If you are not finish last activity then use following code:-**

```
     @Override

     public void onBackPressed() {

     super.onBackPressed();

    }
```

**2. If you are finish last activity then use following code:-**

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intnt=new Intent(CurrentActivity,NewActivity);
    startActivity(intnt);
    finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `intent` line.

**To get a better solution, please provide more information .**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this way.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Hear Pass to intent for the new Activity.
    // then after to put super.onBackPressed();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code
When you click a button in main activity

```
Intent intent= new  Intent(this,NewActivity.class);

 startActivity(intent);
```

Call another activity in these  format  then which will go to the previews  activity when you press back button.  i think you set any additional flag to call another Activity like FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ,FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                moveTaskToBack(true);
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();
            onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, null);
        }
```